# Why does this ajax call not work in IE?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

Works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari, etc.

The JSON response seems fine...I'm guessing it has to do with something I'm doing or not doing in my code:

```
var getPhotos = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Photo',
    headers: {
      'X-Parse-Application-Id': config.parseAppId,
      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': config.parseRestKey
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'where': '{"event": "' + <%= @event.id %> + '"}',
      'order': '-createdAt',
      'limit': '12'
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $('#community-gallery').children().remove();
      data.results.forEach(function (photo) {
        $('#community-gallery').append($('<a href="'+photo.file.url+'" rel="gallery"><img src="'+photo.file.url+'" width="130" style="padding: 0px 15px 15px 0;" /></a>'));
      })
    },
    error: function () {
      alert('Problem reading photos');
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Do any errors appear in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Array `forEach` method in `data.results.forEach` which is only supported in IE9+, see the compatibility table at the bottom of:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Also you are using `$` inside your `append()` call when it should just be the html content.

Comment: You can do it that way, it won't cause an error, just a bit unnecessary.

Comment: Cleaned it up...that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**cache: false,** 
is also pretty important in IE from my experience